# Fragment transition clears data visually (android)

Tags: android, android-fragments, gridview

Lets say I have a fragment with ListView or GridView with images. When I transition using programmatic way or back button I see these listview/gridview data been cleared visually in-between animation. Other controls like textviews dont have this problem. This behavior creates bad visual effect.

Following is the code I use for fragment transitions.

Is there away to reduce this ugly visual impact.

```
        String ttag = fragment
                .getClass().toString();
        Fragment tempF = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(ttag);

        if (tempF != null && tempF.isVisible())
            return;
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putParcelable(Utils.FRAGMENT_INPUT_KEY, fragment.getInput());
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                .beginTransaction();

        fragmentTransaction.setAllowOptimization(true);
        fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fragment_enter,
                R.anim.fragment_exit, R.anim.fragment_leftenter,
                R.anim.fragment_leftexit);
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment, fragment, ttag);

        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```

Following fragment has top level view pager which loads fragments with gridview with images. The visual issue occurs when grid-view is cleared on sub-level fragment. Top level fragment does not have such issue.

Top Fragment life cycle methods with viewpager for tabs.

```
ViewPager viewPager;
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onActivityCreated(bundle);

    activity = getActivity();
    resource = activity.getResources();
    view = getView();

    viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    // some other setup

 }

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
}


@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();

    try {
        Field childFragmentManager = Fragment.class.getDeclaredField("mChildFragmentManager");
        childFragmentManager.setAccessible(true);
        childFragmentManager.set(this, null);

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

    try {

        if(viewPager != null) {
            viewPager.setAdapter(null);
            viewPager.removeAllViews();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

        int x = 0;
    }
}
```

Sub Tab level fragment with gridview of images loaded with, which gets cleared on back button press.

```
GridView list;
GridViewIncompleteAdapter adapter;
ArrayList<String> puzzelList = null;
ArrayList<PuzzelFileData> imagePuzzelList = null;
Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onActivityCreated(bundle);

    activity = getActivity();
    resource = activity.getResources();
    View view = getView();

    puzzelList = new ArrayList<String>();
    imagePuzzelList = new ArrayList<PuzzelFileData>();

    path = Utils.getAppFilePath(activity);
    path = path + Utils.INC_FOLDER;

    list = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.listIncomplete);
    Point p = Utils.getDisplaySize(activity);
 }

 @Override
 public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    if(task != null)
        task.cancel(true);

    if(handler != null && runnable != null)
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);

}

@Override
public  void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();

    if(puzzelList != null)
        puzzelList.clear();

    if(imagePuzzelList != null)
        imagePuzzelList.clear();

    if(adapter != null)
        adapter.disponse();
}
```

top Layout with a tab view,

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/frag"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
        android:id="@+id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Layout with a grid view,

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_inc_nodata"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/LOADING_DATA"
        android:textColor="@color/subtitle_text_color"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_smallmedium"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/listIncomplete"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="3" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please, show lifecycle methods from problematic fragment.

Comment: I added fragment methods. Please let me know if something is unclear. Thanks

Comment: `view = getView();` inside `onActivityCreated` doesn't looks good. Based on that I assume you're declaring `<fragment/>` inside xml layout of activity, am I right?

Comment: I have added the UI as well. I am not doing what you said. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code, you're clearing list inside `onDestroy` by your own:

```
@Override 
public  void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    if(puzzelList != null)
        puzzelList.clear();

    if(imagePuzzelList != null)
        imagePuzzelList.clear();

    if(adapter != null)
        adapter.disponse(); 
}
```

Also, you're **replacing** your fragment, so `onDestroy` should be called in this case. Keep in mind the life-cycle flow, that's in your case will be:

```
Fragment1.onPause();
Fragment1.onStop();
Fragment1.onDestroy();
Fragment2.onCreate();
Fragment2.onResume();
```

For better understanding you could display bitmaps properly, I'd suggest you check [Handling Bitmaps](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/index.html).

Comment: thanks for the input, I thought when we reach onDestroy fragment is not visible anymore. If this is the behavior based on my code,  how do I clear data without having a nasty visual effect.

Comment: @pats Why you've decided to clear lists during `onDestroy`? What did you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to release data on fragments. There is a fragment with 400 bitmaps, which is heavy on memory. So I needed those to be cleared programatically without relying on GC. If I clear them ondistory, it is visible for the user. Thats the problem I am facing. I dont know anywhere else/life cycle method to do this data release.

Comment: @pats You never shouldn't hold `400 bitmaps` in memory simultaneously.

Comment: they are small, but thats not my question. Is there away to release resources without visual effect

Comment: @pats you could clean your data from `onDetach` instead of `onDestroy`